# Can't uninstall LibreOffice 4 and can't upgrade to LibreOffice 5

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, libreoffice

Context: Windows 10 64bit.

I have LibreOffice 4.4.5.2 (32bit) installed and I want to upgrade to LibreOffice 5 (64bit). I find that I can't upgrade to 5 and can't remove 4 due to a registry key issue (which also appears when trying to upgrade.)

According to Event Viewer, in the Applications panel, there's an Error which was logged during the last attempt to uninstall LO4. It reads,

```
Product: LibreOffice 4.4.5.2 -- Error 1402.
Could not open key:  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE32\Software\Classes\.pcd\OpenWithProgIDs.  
System error 5.  
Verify that you have sufficient access to that key, or contact your support personnel.
```

Now given that the uninstaller has to run with Administrator privileges it seems odd that I would not have "sufficient access to that key."

What's odder is that there's an `HKLM32` in the first place. I've run `RegEdit` and I can find *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes.pcd\OpenWithProgIDs* but no sign of a *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE**32**\Software\Classes.pcd\OpenWithProgIDs*.

Where to from here?

Comment: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/59687/upgrade-fails-with-hkey_local_machine32-error/ suggests running [ccleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner) fixed the issue

Comment: I have run CCleaner a number of times. I use it frequently anyway as it's one of my must-have tools. It sadly has made no difference to this issue.

Comment: Two years later and I'm using LibreOffice 6.